# Firefox Quantum (ver >= 57) - How Can I Hide the Horizontal Tab Bar with TreeStyle Tabs?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, css

Tree Style Tabs is an excellent plugin and probably the main reason I use Firefox. With the newer versions of Firefox, Tree Style Tabs works nicely, but I can still see the same tabs duplicated across the top horizontally.

How can I hide the horizontal Tab Bar until Firefox incorporates this functionality?

Plugin Firefox Page: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/ 
Plugin Homepage:        http://piro.sakura.ne.jp/xul/_treestyletab.html.en

Comment: those with big screens might also like Tab Center Redux as it looks bigger then tree style tabs.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The horizontal tab bar can be hidden with the following steps:

1. Confirm or Create:

   ```
   Linux: ~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile name>/chrome/userChrome.css
   Windows: %AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile name>\chrome\userChrome.css
   macOS: ~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/<profile name>/chrome/userChrome.css
   ```
2. Add the Following code to: **userChrome.css**

   ```
   @namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");
   #TabsToolbar {
       visibility: collapse !important;
   }
   ```

   ^Note: Line 1 is required when creating the file and does not need to be included more than once.
3. Restart Firefox

As this is a custom workaround until either Firefox itself allows the horizontal tab bar to be hidden, or the TreeStyle Tabs extension itself hides it, this information may become dated in the future.

```
Confirmed Testing: Firefox Nightly 58.0a1 (2017-10-23) (64-bit)
```

As of Firefox 69:  By default, userChrome.css modifications are disabled in Firefox. You need to make sure that on the about:config page in Firefox, the toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets preference is set to true and then restart the browser. (see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1541233)

EDIT: Added macOS. h/t: @coderuby

Comment: Confirmed working on 57.0 64-bit, Linux Mint.

Comment: Works on macOS 10.11.6 with Firefox 58.0b4. On macOS the userChrome.css can be found or created under: `~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/<profile name>/chrome/userChrome.css`

Comment: Note: if you open a new window, you'll still have to click the Tree Style Tab button if you open new tabs. Otherwise they'll be open, but hidden.

Comment: @Anssssss There is a plugin hotkey of F1 that toggles the sidebar. Details can be found in the description (at least as of ver 2.2.9 of Tree Style Tab)

Comment: Users who view issue this may also want to hide the Tree Style Tabs heading that appears in the sidebar:  `#sidebar-header { display: none; }`

Comment: just FYI. I did not have a chrome folder there neither userChrome.css file! Had to create it, but it works.

Comment: I put it here: AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\d0blabla\chrome  Note the "Roaming".  There is also an up-to-date mozilla dir tree under "appData/local" but that did not work.

Comment: This is still needed and still works in 65.0a1 (2018-10-30) (64-bit).

Comment: This solution also works for Tab Center Redux.